# difference between structure operators in c

Tags: c

I'm new to structures in c, I've been researching the difference between the . operator, and the -> operator. But I can't seem the find resources that explain what I want to know. So, why if I make structure without typedef, can I use it directly such as "header.first = x", and not having to say "struct header varName"? Also, what is the difference between the . and -> in this example, because it seems in this case I can use them interchangeably.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}node;

struct header{
        int count;
        node *first;
}header;
int main()
{

   node *curptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   printf("%p\n",curptr);
   header.first = curptr;
   printf("%p\n",header.first);
   header.count = 10;
   printf("%i\n\n\n",header.count);


   node* current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   current->data = 5;
   current->next = NULL;
   printf("%i\n",current->data);
   printf("%p",current);
}
```

Comment: `a->b` means `(*a).b`, nothing more and nothing less. You cannot use them interchangeably , and typedef has nothing to do with it

Comment: Typically, you use `->` when the left side is a pointer, in order to avoid having to deference it. In other words, it is syntax sugar, a shorthand, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`struct header { ... } header;` is simultaneously creating the struct type (`struct header`) as well as creating a global variable (named `header`, of type `struct header`). It is equivalent to doing:

```
struct header { ... };
struct header header;
```

When you write `header.first = x`, what you're doing is just modifying the global object named `header`.

`typedef struct node { ... } node;` is simultaneously creating the struct type (`struct node`) as well as a typedef to it (`node`). It is equivalent to doing:

```
struct node { ... };
typedef struct node node;
```

As for `.` vs `->`: `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`. It's just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

Answer (score 0):

struct in c is a place in memory which is big enough to keep data for all its fields. As with any other objects in 'c' you have a choice to use it as a variable or use a pointer to it. A pointer is essentially a memory address of this variable.

Also, every variable in 'c' has a type. The latter behaves like a template for creating variables and check their usage.

So, in the following example you create a struct type `struct header` and describe what it contains.

```
struct header{
    int count;
    node *first;
};
```

Now, using the type, you can create the variable named `my_header`:

```
struct header my_header;
```

or, as in your example, variable `header`.

```
struct header header;
```

As in you example you can combine both into a single statement.

Now, if you created a variable of type 'struct header', you can access its members using the `.` operator. The following operator will cause 'c' to access member count of your struct variable. It will calculate correct place in memory to put '10' into it.

```
header.count = 10;
```

as for pointers, you can create a variable which will keep an address to your object. In 'c' it needs to know what type of object it points to. So, the pointer `ptr` in the following example is assigned address `&` of the variable `header`.

```
struct header *ptr = &header;
```

Now you can use the pointer to access fields in the header, but it requires a different syntax `->`. so, the following statement will be equivalent to the previous one:

```
 ptr->count = 10;
```

Note that in both cases '10' was assigned to absolutely the same object, field of the variable 'header'.

Also to make life easier ant to stop typing `struct` every time, you can use the `typedef` operator to declare a named type, i.e.

```
typedef struct node myNodeType;
typedef struct node node;
```

now you have to 'named' types: `myNodeType` and `node` which are the same. you can use them to declare variables and pointers:

```
 myNodeType var1; // variable
 node *next;  // pointer.
```

and as in case with variable declaration, you can combine it with struct declaration as in your example.

And `malloc` just allocates a chunk of dynamic memory and returns its address, aka pointer to it. so, `node* current = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` just assigns address of allocated memory to the pointer `current`.

Hope it helps a bit.